# Stop Javascript in a VBA Web Browser

Tags: javascript, vba, excel

I'm trying to get all tables from a specific webpage. For that, I built a VBA macro (PatenteCatcher) to input some info. and navigate thru the website until he finds a specific webpage that contains those tables. The string containing the specific's webpage URL is urlfocado3.  Then, I call a second VBA macro called PegaTabelas which captures every table in this specific table and save them on a sheet. The macro is doing it well. But, the thing is: inside the webpage that contains the tables, there is javascript tied to a specific table line, opening some extra information that I really doesn’t want.

In short, I would like to disable a specific javascript inside that page. If it isn’t possible, I would like to disable all javascripts in the specific page. Unfortunately, I can’t disable scripting at IE since my code won’t do well without it.

Here is the HTML code from the page that I would like to disable:

```
<a href="javascript:void(0)" onmouseout="hideMe('classificacao0')" onmouseover="showMe('classificacao0','hidden')" onClick="DisableHide()" class=normal>
                            C07C 229/40    <b>;&nbsp;</b>
                        </a>
                        <div  id="classificacao0" style="BACKGROUND-COLOR: #ffffff; BORDER-BOTTOM: #000000 1px; BORDER-LEFT: #000000 1px; BORDER-RIGHT: #000000 1px; BORDER-TOP: #000000 1px; HEIGHT: 20px; POSITION: absolute; VISIBILITY: hidden; WIDTH: 300px; Z-INDEX: 10; layer-background-color: #FFFFFF">
                            <table width="100%" border="1" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="5" bordercolor="#006363" bordercolorlight="#B5D6AD">
                                <tr><td align="center" bgcolor="#B5D6AD">
                                        <table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="1" cellpadding="0">
                                            <tr>
                                                <td width="30"><a href="javascript:EnableHide('classificacao0');"><img src="../jsp/imagens/bt_layer.gif" width="26" height="16" border="0" name="class"></a></td>
                                            </tr>
                                        </table>
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <td align="left" bgcolor="#ffffff">
                                <font class="normal"><center><b>C07C 229/40    </b></center>
                                <hr size=2 width="100%" align="center" color="#B5D6AD">

                                    Compostos contendo grupos amino e carboxila ligados ao mesmo esqueleto de carbono <br>com grupos amino ligados a átomos de carbono de pelo menos um anel aromático de seis membros e grupos carboxila ligados a átomos de carbono acíclicos do mesmo esqueleto de carbono;

                                </font>
                                </td>
                                </tr>
                            </table>
                        </div>
```

Here is my macros:

```
Sub PatenteCatcher()
    Dim IE As Object
    Dim strURL As String
    Dim strUsername As String
    Dim strPassword As String
    Dim PedidoPatente As Object
    Dim urlfocado As String
    Dim urlfocado2 As String
    Dim urlfocado3 As String
    Dim ApertaBotao As Object
    Dim patentefoco As String
    Dim doc As Object


    Set IE = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
    IE.Visible = True

    strURL = "https://gru.inpi.gov.br/pPI/servlet/LoginController?action=login"
    strURL2 = "https://gru.inpi.gov.br/pPI/jsp/patentes/PatenteSearchBasico.jsp"

    IE.navigate strURL

    While IE.Busy
        DoEvents
    Wend


    IE.navigate strURL2

    While IE.Busy
        DoEvents
    Wend
         While IE.Busy
        DoEvents
    Wend
    Posicao = Worksheets("Operação").Cells(1, 2)
IE.document.getElementsByName("NumPedido").Item.innerText = “9600975”
     While IE.Busy
        DoEvents
    Wend

Set ApertaBotao = IE.document.all.Item("botao")
        ApertaBotao.Value = "submit"
        ApertaBotao.Click
I = 1

While IE.Busy
        DoEvents
Wend

I = 1
Set linkCollecting = IE.document.getElementsByTagName("A")
    For Each link In linkCollecting
    Worksheets("Rascunho").Cells(I, 1) = link
    I = I + 1
    Next
urlfocado = Worksheets("Rascunho").Cells(8, 1)

If urlfocado <> "" Then
    IE.navigate urlfocado

    Set doc = IE.document
    While IE.Busy
        DoEvents
    Wend
    Worksheets("Rascunho").Activate
    Call PegaTabelas(doc)

Else
    MsgBox ("Erro! A base de dados do INPI nao esta disponivel. Nada de novo ate aqui.")
    Worksheets("Rascunho").Activate
End If

While IE.Busy
    DoEvents
Wend

''IE.Quit
```

End Sub

```
    Sub PegaTabelas(doc As Object)

        Dim ws As Worksheet
        Dim rng As Range
        Dim tbl As Object
        Dim rw As Object
        Dim cl As Object
        Dim tabno As Long
        Dim nextrow As Long
        Dim I As Long

        Set ws = Worksheets("Rascunho")

        For Each tbl In doc.getElementsByTagName("TABLE")
            tabno = tabno + 1
            nextrow = nextrow + 1
            Set rng = ws.Range("B" & nextrow)
            rng.Offset(, -1) = "Table " & tabno
            For Each rw In tbl.Rows
                For Each cl In rw.Cells
                    rng.Value = cl.outerText
                    Set rng = rng.Offset(, 1)
                    I = I + 1
                Next cl
                nextrow = nextrow + 1
                Set rng = rng.Offset(1, -I)
                I = 0
            Next rw
        Next tbl

        ws.Cells.ClearFormats
    End Sub
```

Comment: Unless your code is clicking any of those links shown in the HTML you posted, that script will not execute, and so it's unclear why it might be a problem...

Comment: That javascript contains a script that popup a info. box. which contain informations that I don't need. The problem is: when I get those tables with the PegaTabelas macro, it also capture those "extra" info, unabling to identify the real info.

Comment: At which point does the popup appear?

Comment: When I pass my mouse over. My code doesn't do anything related to this, but when it tries to get that table, it captures the whole text (the text inside the and table and the text inside that popup). You can take a look at the page by running the code. The  C07C 229/40; C07C 233/40;A61K 31/405 is the info that I want. But when you pass you mouse, more unwanted text appears.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try something like this to remove the contents of the pop-up divs.  I'm assuming they have an id like "classificacao[number]"

```
Dim divs

Set divs = doc.getElementsByTagName("div")
for each div in divs
   if div.id like "classificacao*" then 
       div.innerHTML=""
   end if
next div
```